# How can i detect if List<string> was changed ? And what is the last item that was added?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a timer tick event:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combindedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ListsExtractions.myList);
    richTextBox1.SelectAll();
    richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    richTextBox1.Text = combindedString;
}
```

The timer is set to 50000 and the time is running all the time over and over again.
Now the `List<string> myList` when i'm running my program has, for example, 3 items:

```
Index 0: Hello world
Index 1: 24/7/2014 21:00
Index 2: http://test.com
```

After 50 seconds there are two options: either the List not changed or it has changed/longer.
If not changed do nothing but if changed get the latest added item. For example, if the list has now been changed to this...

```
Index 0: This is the latest item added in index 0
Index 1: 24/7/2014 22:00
Index 2: http://www.google.com
Index 3: ""
Index 4: Hello world
Index 5: 24/7/2014 21:00
Index 6: http://test.com
```

... then I need to do another two actions:

1. When running the program for the first time, check if the most recent item (the string at `Index 0` in this example) contains two words/strings. If it does, then do something, otherwise, do nothing.
   However, if it does contain the words/strings and we do "do something", only do it once after 50 seconds; don't do it again even if the words/string exist again in index 0.
2. After 50 seconds if the List changed and in `Index 0` this words/strings exists, do something and again only once after 50 seconds.  If the List didn't change, don't do it again even if the words/string still exist in index 0.

   ```
   if (rlines[0].Contains("צבע אדום") || rlines[0].Contains("אזעקה"))
   {
       timer3.Start();            
   }
   ```

I want to start `timer3` only if one of the words/strings exist in index 0.

If nothing has changed after 50 seconds don't start `timer3` again.

Only if after 50 seconds or later the List changed and one of the words/strings exist in index 0 again only then start timer 3 again.

Comment: I would suggest using ObservableCollection<T> rather than List<T>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Generic `List<T>` class does not support notifications for list changes.
What you are looking for is [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx).
It has a [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) that triggered when the collection is being modified.

You can use it in the following manner:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

ObservableCollection<string> myList;

//The cnstructor 
public MyClassname()
{
  this.myList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  this.myList.CollectionChanged += myList_CollectionChanged;
}

void myList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        //list changed - an item was added.
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            //Do what ever you want to do when an item is added here...
            //the new items are available in e.NewItems
        }
}
```

Comment: Avi i'm trying to use the ObservableCollection<T> but it's never get into the event. I did: myl = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            myl.CollectionChanged += myl_CollectionChanged; i used a breakpoint after it's doing the line myl.CollectionChanged += myl_CollectionChanged; it's continue the form1 constructor it's never get into void myl_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) why ?

Comment: The event will be called when the list is modified. `myl.CollectionChanged += myl_CollectionChanged;` is simply telling the method `myl_CollectionChanged` to the event of `myl.CollectionChanged`. It is expected the the constructor will continue rather than jump to the `myl_CollectionChanged` method. Try the following: put a breakpoint in the `myl_CollectionChanged` method and Add an item to the list. Then the method will be triggered.

Comment: This works only when a row adds to list. If a row erase from list, or a cell edit, it doesn't raise.

Answer (score -3):

To detect if your `list` was changed , check your list item count using :
You have to have `temp` variable containing current list item count :

`int temp = list.Count;//` Gets the number of elements contained in the List.

then when you add item:

```
list.add("string one");
```

then use the temp variable to do like this :

```
if(temp != list.Count){
Console.WriteLine("list was changed.");
}
```

then of course if your list is not sorted:
you can get the last item with :

`list[list.Count - 1];` //last item in the list that was added

Comment: `list[foo] = bar` doesn't change the count, nor does `foo` have to be the latest index to be changed.

Comment: This method will not detect the case where an equal number of items are added and removed from the collection, or if its members have changed internal to themselves.